# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `CSSTransition`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-transition-group

I want to make a popup that opens smoothly. To do this, I installed react-transition-group. Now the site has an error - Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `CSSTransition`. But the popup opens smoothly. When I click close, an error is displayed - React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child. How can this be resolved?

```js
const Header = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const togglePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-content">
        <div className="header-input">
          <input
            className="add-adv"
            type="button"
            value="Add advertisement"
            onClick={togglePopup}
          />
          <CSSTransition
            in={isOpen}
            classNames="alert"
            timeout={300}
            unmountOnExit
          >
            {isOpen && (
              <AddAdvertisement
                content={
                  <>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter title"
                      value={enteredTitle}
                      onChange={titleChangeHandler}
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter latitude"
                      value={enteredLatitude}
                      onChange={latitudeChangeHandler}
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter longitude"
                      value={enteredLongitude}
                      onChange={longitudeChangeHandler}
                    />
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" onClick={submitHandler} />
                  </>
                }
                handleClose={togglePopup}
              />
            )}
          </CSSTransition>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const AddAdvertisement = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="popup-box">
      <div className="box">
        <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>
          x
        </span>
        {props.content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When using some **third-party packages as dependencies**, not all of those packages are written in `TypeScript`. Therefore the packages developers provide also an installation for the type declarations if other developers want to use those types in their `TypeScript` projects.

In your case to install the package `react-transition-group` :

- first `npm i react-transition-group`
- then (when usinig TypeScript) `npm install @types/react-transition-group`

If you want to know more about Type Declarations check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html) official link